# Write in a transparent colour in expression blend (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I am trying to build a windows phone live tile. I want some text on the tile that is the accent colour. What this means is that I need to draw some text on the tile that is transparent. I don't seem to be able to write in the transparent colour.

I have a User Control which is 173 by 173 pixels which I save as a png file. I use this png as the image for the live tile. The transparent bits of the image come out in the current accent colour.

Any ideas how to write in the transparent colour in xaml?

Comment: Are you trying to have the background color shown through the tile?

Comment: Yes. That is it in a nutshell.

Comment: And when you saved your .png you explicitly marked it to preserve transparency? Have you tried a compound Path?

Comment: The transparent parts of the tile work fine. I have a tile that is completely transparent (Accent colour). With a white star in the top right. On top of the star I want to be able to put the unread count in the accent colour. This means that the font has to "cut through" the white star to reaveal the background below it (which is transparent it self).

Comment: Ah ok so if I'm understanding correctly what you actually want to do is Bind the Foreground color of your numeric count (TextBlock) to the Accent Color via the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is to be expected.  In your original question you are effectively saying "Write invisible text on top of the image", and that's what you're getting (imagine writing in invisible ink on a photograph).  You effectively need to do one of two things.

1) Figure out which pixels are part of the text you're writing, and "remove" them from the image so the background colour shows through, or
2) Write text in the background colour ({StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush})

*EDIT*

You can probably achieve what you need using an [Opacity Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320.aspx). Apologies for only providing that as a link as I haven't done this myself.

Comment: Yes, Step 1 is what I need to do. Any ideas how to do that in blend?

Comment: I've never done it, to be honest, but maybe an opacity mask would help out?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320.aspx

Comment: An opacity mask... hmmm. I will have a go with this. Thanks

Comment: Definitely +1 for Opacity Mask, completely forgot of that option.